# Fill React app with WordPress REST API

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs

I just finished to learn react.js basics, and now I'm building an app that could get datas from a WordPress installation, via wp-rest-api.

I succeed in getting datas with an ajax call in a non-react script, and now I'm trying to implement this into my react app.

I've got only one react component that is App.js, and I'd like fill the App state with datas from WordPress, but failed...

This is my app.js code :

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        posts : {}
    }

    render() {

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost/overwatch/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');
        xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(){
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
                console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
            }
        });
        xhr.send(null);

        return(
            <h1>App root</h1>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

The console do display expected datas, but all what I tried to push them in the app state failed.
Could someone help please ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use setState method to store data in to the react state. And also it's advised to make Ajax calls on componentDidMount lifecycle method. Not inside render method.

```
componentDidMount(){
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost/overwatch/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');
  xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(){
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
    let data = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
      this.setState({
        posts: data
        }, function(){
          console.log(this.state.posts)
      })
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps but won't work because 'this' refers to XHR object and not to the App component.

Comment: Resolved with const that = this, and further that.setState(...)
Thanks again for launch me on the right track :)